# Building a slideout image gallery w/ jquery-- seeking suggestions for plugins or code snippets

Tags: javascript, jquery, gallery

I'm trying to build an image gallery (or, ideally, find a jquery plugin) that meets the following specifications:

1. Full-size images in #left div, thumbnails wrapped in links in #right div.
2. Clicking a #right div thumb causes the corresponding full-size image to slide out from the right side of the #left frame to the center
3. After full-size image loads, the thumbnails in #right fade out to reveal the description of each image-- possibly stored in the alt tag, more likely stored in a span within the link
4. When #right thumbs fade, a button appears that allows the user to click and fade the thumbnails back in.

I don't know any javascript, so I'm at a loss as to where to begin with something like this. My expertise is front-end, but unfortunately I find myself a de facto developer these days. Such is life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use this:
http://playground.marmaladeontoast.co.uk/jquery/galleria/demo/demo_02.htm

But without any javascript knowledge, you will struggle to get any plugin to exactly what you want...

But!

I have just given a couple of lectures on an introduction to javascript, so you might find the slides useful

[Introduction to JavaScript](http://www.slideshare.net/sydlawrence/introduction-to-javascript-6856194)

[JavaScript Development](http://www.slideshare.net/sydlawrence/javascript-development)

In fact I have literally just started the second years on a javascript module, and my slides will be going online as when I do them, so keep an eye on my [slideshare](http://slideshare.net/sydlawrence)

I hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks! I was considering Galleria, but as you mentioned, it's difficult to manipulate plugins without any javascript knowledge. It's a problem I've run into before. I'll poke at it a bit, though, and see if I can make some progress. Worse case scenario I'll contact a real developer. And thanks for the tutorial link. I'll check it out!